# Typo3 9.5: Crawl pages with front end login

Tags: typo3-9.x, tx-indexed-search

I undertook the work on an intranet based on Typo3 v9.5.23. They're using indexed_search v9.5.23 and crawler v9.1.5 to crawl the pages but in the database table `tx_crawler_queue` in the column `result_data` I get `{"content":"\"403 Access denied\""}` for every page.

To see the pages you have to login as a front end user. What do I have to do to crawl those pages?

I'm using the console with the following commands:

```
vendor/bin/typo3 crawler:flushQueue all
vendor/bin/typo3 crawler:buildQueue 69 intranet --depth=2
vendor/bin/typo3 crawler:processQueue
```

Comment: in the [crawler config](https://docs.typo3.org/p/aoepeople/crawler/9.2/en-us/Configuration/ConfigurationRecords/Index.html) you find `Crawl with FE user groups`. any FE-login needs a FE user group which you should select.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ Wow, I must be blind. That worked, thank you!

Comment: as this is the answer I made an answer from my comment, which you can accept as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [crawler config](https://docs.typo3.org/p/aoepeople/crawler/9.2/en-us/Configuration/ConfigurationRecords/Index.html) you find a field `Crawl with FE user groups`.

As any FE-login needs a FE user group you should select the possible groups for crawling.